# How to apply Material-UI table style to a data loaded from CSV?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, csv, material-ui

I want to upload a CSV file on a button click. Everything works fine, except how a table is styled.

This [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/x9w113kmpp) does not use any styling of a table. I want to use Material-UI's [Table element](https://material-ui.com/demos/tables/).

The tutorial on [react-csv-to-table](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-csv-to-table) explains how to apply bootstrap style, but I need to apply Material-UI:

```
<CsvToHtmlTable
  data={sampleData}
  csvDelimiter=","
  tableClassName="table table-striped table-hover"
/>
```

In Material-UI it looks a style is applied row-wise. is it possible to do something similar to `tableClassName="table table-striped table-hover"`. I would need a basic table with pagination.